# Push back insted of popto showing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
@try {
        NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        NSUInteger totalelement = [viewContrlls count];
        UIViewController *LastElementController = [viewContrlls objectAtIndex:totalelement-2];
        [self GotoDifferentViewWithAnimation:LastElementController];

    } @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
```

I am trying to get the last visited viewcontroller and pushback there with animation using the above code. It's showing the last visited viewcontroller properly like,

```
 LastElementController  --- <RRLoginViewController: 0x10b324e60>
```

But getting complietime err,

```
Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<RRLoginViewController: 0x10b324e60>)
```

any help.....

Comment: Is [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] working for you?

Comment: ya, that is working fine..

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to push a view controller that's already in the navigation stack. Hence, you cannot "go back" to the view controller via "pushing it again".

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:LastElementController animated:YES];
```

will do the job, but I think you want to save the condition of that View Controller.